# How to take backup of a partition from another partition

Tags: macos, backup, partition, restore

I have two partition one for *Yosemite OS* as *Macintosh HD*  and another for *El Capitan OS* as *El Capitan*

Now *El-capitan* part is not *booting up* and I have to take a data backup of El-Capitan from Yosemite so that I can reformat the El-Capitan partition and later restore from the back up.

I couldn't find any tools that does this.

Any pointers to achieve this is highly appreciated !

[image: screen shot of El-Capitan from Yosemite]

Thanks

Comment: Why did the ElCap partition lose bootability? Maybe it's easier to solve this problem instead of copying GBs of data? Usually you can even simply reinstall ElCap using the latest installer version on a current system without losing any exisiting (user) data

Answer (score 1):

I can think of several ways of making a back of your El Capitan partition, provided the El Capitan partition still mounts when you're booting up from Yosemite partition then you could use Time Machine to select the El Capitan Partition in System Pref/Time Machine.

Or copy the entire contents of the El Capitan partition onto an external hard drive when you boot from Yosemite.

Comment: Copying is not allowed as it has red minus mark in the folders I guess

Comment: Yes but thats not going to stop you from copying the data. The red minus just means you don't have permissions to view the contents so all you need to do is give yourself permission. Start by using the "Get Info" on the folders and click the padlock at the bottom to unlock, then click + to add yourself to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to back up or make an image of any partition on any drive you can use Apple's own Time Machine.

You could just copy the files you need to keep to another location manually and then re-install the operating system but you can't and should not just copy the contents of any other system folder for re-use later as there will be permissions issues and other problems galore.

You could use other backup programs like SuperDuper, Carbon Copy Cloner and the like which will make (among other things) a bootable image of any (already bootable) drive.

Comment: SuperDuper and Carbon Copy Cloner are paid softwares

Comment: Can't we make bootable drive using TimeMachine ?

Comment: Yes they are. you will find that most "softwares" that do important things with your Mac will cost you money. I personally would never trust 3rd party backup software that *doesn't* cost something. And Time Machine can make a bootable backup.